# Collapsible flexible-width sidebar using only CSS

Tags: html, css, transition, flexbox

Let's assume I have a collapsible fixed-width sidebar defined like this:

HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
    SIDEBAR
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    lorem bla bla
    <button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0].classList.toggle('collapsed')">
      toggle Sidebar
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height:100px;
}

.sidebar {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: all .25s;
}

.sidebar.collapsed {
  left:-200px;
  margin-right:-200px;
}
```

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJRYJb

### So here's the question:

How can I go from there to a *flexible-width* sidebar?

Here are the constraints:

- no javascript (I want the browser to deal with the layouting – not me)
- the sidebar must not overlap the content
- when collapsed, the sidebar's right border needs to be aligned with the window's left border (to be able to attach an absolutely positioned tab on the right side that's always visible)
- the width of the sidebar shouldn't change if collapsed to avoid reflows during the transition
- smooth transition without any sudden jumps
- modern CSS (flexboxes, calc) is fine

The main issue here is that I can't find a way to say `margin-right: -100%` where `100%` refers to the width of sidebar

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: javascript is fine for triggering the collapse logic. But I don't want to use javascript for the layouting.

Comment: How about `width: auto;
  display: flex;` for `.sidebar`

Comment: and what do I put in `.sidebar.collapsed`?

Comment: What does *flexible-width* mean? Like `flex: 1`?

Comment: it means: should take up as much width as it's children – as if it was `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 4):

How about changing the `width` instead of `position` on click? I use `max-width` in this case, it works almost the same as unknown width. This will probably cause the content reflow on the sidebar, so use `white-space:nowrap` if it's acceptable.

http://jsfiddle.net/dn4ge901/

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.sidebar {
    background: #ccc;
    transition: all .1s;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
.sidebar.collapsed {
    max-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
    <div class="content">lorem bla bla
        <button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0].classList.toggle('collapsed')">toggle Sidebar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another workaround is using `transform` width `position` together, but the animation effect will be slightly different.

http://jsfiddle.net/vkhyp960/

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.sidebar {
    background: #ccc;
    transition: all .1s;
}
.sidebar.collapsed {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
        <div>SIDEBAR</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">lorem bla bla
        <button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0].classList.toggle('collapsed')">toggle Sidebar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question says "*the width of the sidebar shouldn't change*"

Comment: yes, it's getting close! However, this solution causes the contents of the sidebar to reflow since the width changes during the transition. That's something I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: @Daniel can you use `sidebar {white-space: nowrap;}` - http://jsfiddle.net/dn4ge901/1/

Comment: the contents of the sidebar are going to be really complex components. So this probably doesn't work :(

Comment: @Daniel there is another way using `transform`, but the animation is different - http://jsfiddle.net/dn4ge901/2/

Comment: yes, I've played around with `transform: translateX(-100%);` already. This however doesn't cause the `.content` pane to adapt. (I still need to set `margin-right` to a negative value)

Comment: @Daniel check that that demo, I also set it to absolute position, so no need negative margin to be set.

Comment: nice! Of course the transition isn't very smooth yet, but it's definitely better than anything I have come up with so far. If you update your answer you'll get a +1 from me :)

Comment: @Daniel sure it's updated. I'm willing to see if there is a perfect solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Piggy-backing off Pangloss' suggestion re: the transform... you can just apply a negative margin to the content if you know the width of the sidebar. No need to have the sidebar switch to absolute positioning.

```
@mixin transitionAll() {
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
  flex: 1 0 300px;
  background: #333;
  height: 100%;
  @include transitionAll();
  &.is-collapsed {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #999;
  @include transitionAll();
  &.is-full-width {
    margin-left: -300px;
  }
}
```

--

```
<div class="container">
  <aside class="sidebar">
  </aside>
  <section class="content">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Toggle</button>
  </section>
</div>
```

--

```
$(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('is-collapsed');
    $('.content').toggleClass('is-full-width');
  });
});
```

See the Pen [LxRYQB](http://codepen.io/JFlo/pen/LxRYQB/) by Jason Florence ([@JFlo](http://codepen.io/JFlo)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

Comment: Thanks for your input! Unfortunately, this isn't quite what I was looking for, since I need a solution for a *flexible-width* sidebar, i.e. the sidebar's width adapts to it's children. (e.g. because it's `display: inline-block`)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I **do** have a partly *js solution*. The animation itself is done entirely with CSS, it just resolves the `width:auto` problem. You just set the width of the sidebar domElement with js, when the element is loaded:

`` domElement.style.width = `${parseInt(domElement.offsetWidth)}px`; ``

This resolves the 'unknown' width problem. And you can use your `.collapsed` approach just as you like to do. The only adjustment is that you'll need to add `!important` to the `.collapsed {width: 300px !important;}` width value.